# how to save an output from terminal to a variable

Tags: c++, ubuntu-14.04

I am writing a c++ code where i take the process name from user and then i get the process id using command `pgrep process_name` then i kill it using command `kill process_id`, the problem is i can't save the output of command `pgrep` in a variable to re-use it again , thats's what i reached so far
am using ubuntu's terminal

p.s(`stringcat` is a function i mad to concatenate words i use in my command )

```
   cout<<"enter the name of the process you wanna stop : ";
   cin>>in;
   string PID;
   command=stringcat("pgrep ",in,"");
   /*
   const char*temp = command.c_str();
   PID=system(temp);
   */
   command=stringcat("kill",PID,"");
   const char*temp2 = command.c_str();
   system(temp2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`popen` is the most simple choice, or you can use `fork` and replace stdout of child process with what you want.